# Partition Function- Are the energies of the individual microstates, free energies?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

$$Z=\sum_i e^{-\beta E_i}$$
I am relatively new to statistical mechanics, and I am wondering if the individual energies ($E_i$) in the equation above are free energies associated with each microstate? If it is, would it be Gibb's Free Energy or Helmholtz's Free Energy?

Comment: It's not free energy, it's energy.

Answer (score 2):

No, the $E_i$s are energies. In statistical mechanics it can be show (see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy#Relation_to_the_canonical_partition_function)) that the Helmotz's free energy $F$ is related to the partition function of the system in the following way
$$
F = -kT\log Z
$$
and all other thermodynamic relations, e.g. that with the Gibbs's free energy, can be found starting from it.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the free energy associated with a particular microstate, and not the entire ensemble?

Comment: @wanlei I'm not sure a possible definition on a single microstate would be meaningful, especially if I think at the relation between the free energy and the entropy of the system.